# Which algorithm or tool to use to classify as good or bad?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, clustering, gmm

I have a feature vector with different data types, Considering all the data in that feature vector. I have to classify as *Good* or *Bad*.

Which algorithm should be used to just get the output Good or bad based on different data types in a feature vector?

The feature vectors are as follows:

[Application_Name(string) , Uptime (Integer) , Criticality factor (0-1 float value) and few integer type ]

Comment: Don't you have any label for your features?

Comment: @Media Updated feature vector in question , Application_Name(string) , Uptime (Integer) , Criticality factor (0-1 float value) and few integer type ]

Comment: Is your task unsupervised?

Comment: @Media , I am kind of new to this , anything is fine which is best ? All the values in vector are available and are uncorrelated .

Comment: I think Media is asking if you already have a set of data labelled 'Good' and 'Bad' for you to train a model on?
If no, then this is an unsupervised task.

Comment: @DanCarter  Yes this is unsupervised task , maybe I was thinking deciding the boundary based  feedback , can the feedback value be included as parameter in feature vector ..Actually i Don;t know ? How do we decide the boundry

Comment: How about random answering? How can you evaluate that what you are doing is not just random?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments I'll try to answer. I guess you don't have the corresponding labeles. What you can do as a solution is that you can use k-means algorithm as the easiest start point to and specify the hyper parameter, k, to two. Then you can find two clusters and you yourself can evaluate the results. As another approach, you can increase the size of k and again evaluate your answers. You can also use Gaussian Mixture Models for finding better non-convex clusters which have better results. The point is that you have to evaluate the results as an expert and label them manually. This task accelerates the labeling process. After that you can employ a simple `MLP` for finding a descriminative model.